# How to split dataframe by latitude in ranges from 90 to -90

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have dataframe that I need to split based on latitude.

The example of dataframe columns:

```
df.glat = [-20, -30, -40, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90, -80, -70 - 60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 10, 20, 30]
```

I was trying to create a column status based on behavior of latitude values:

```
df. status = ['decline', 'decline', 'decline', 'decline', 'decline', 'decline', 'decline', 'decline', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase', 'increase']
```

I need to group it into groups from 90 to -90. In original my dataframe change in this ranges several time.

How can split dataframes into such groups:

```
1 : [-20, -30, -40, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90]
2: [ -80, -70 - 60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 10, 20, 30]
```

I have made a graphic of my ordinal data how the latitude changes:
[image]
So I need to split each range from [-90 to 90] as separate dataframe. Like here from the graphic for example should be 16 splitted dataframes.

I will be grateful for any suggestion!

Comment: Do you want the output to be two separate lists?

Comment: two different dataframes. I think probably I need to have a column 'flag' for each range [-90 , 90]. But I have no idea how to make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'glat': [-20, -30, -40, 10, 20, 30, -40, -50, -60]})

df['is_increasing'] = df['glat'].diff().bfill().gt(0)
df['group'] = df['is_increasing'].diff().bfill().cumsum()

df.groupby('group')['glat'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
group
0    [-20, -30, -40]
1       [10, 20, 30]
2    [-40, -50, -60]
Name: glat, dtype: object
```

P.S. `df` will get a `group` column with group ID, so you can easily split it into separate dataframes later (for example, with `dataframes = [df for _, df in df.groupby('group')]`):

```
   glat  is_increasing  group
0   -20          False      0
1   -30          False      0
2   -40          False      0
3    10           True      1
4    20           True      1
5    30           True      1
6   -40          False      2
7   -50          False      2
8   -60          False      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But can I  when I will have for example 3 groups (or even more) split all of them separately

Comment: @KaterynaLubyk I've updated the answer with an example with 3 groups. Does it work for what you're trying to achieve? (it doesn't look very intuitive, so if it works I'll post an explanation of what's going on there)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works very well and thank you for explanation!